# How does one change the text inside of two separate elements using one jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications, jquery-selectors, functional-programming

I am writing a jQuery function for an image gallery with thumbnails. There is a div at the top of the webpage that will display a larger version of a clicked thumbnail as well as a title and a description.

When the thumbnails are clicked, the title changes as I expect but the description remains the default (defined by HTML).

The thumbnails are in an unordered list like so:

```
<ul class=thumblist id=thumblist>
<li><a title="thumb1" description="this is the first pic"></a></li>
<li><a title="thumb2" description="this is the second pic"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jQuery function:

```
  $('.thumblist a').click(function() {
    $("#title").text(this.title);
    $("#description").text(this.description);         
  });
```

What can I do to fix my markup and achieve the functionality I am looking for?

Comment: Please show the code that displays the larger image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [`attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$('.thumblist a').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $("#title").text($this.attr("title")); // Or `this.title`, see below
  $("#description").text($this.attr("description"));         
});
```

The reason it sort of half-worked is that `title` is a valid HTML attribute that has a [reflected property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-18446827) on the DOM element instance, so `this.title` gave you that attribute; but `description` is not, so there's no reflected `description` property. Using `attr` goes and looks for the actual attribute value.

Ideally, use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) for ad-hoc attributes (like your `description`) not defined by any standard.